# Creating an ImageView with a certain style programatically

Tags: android

I want to do this programatically:

```
<ImageView style="@style/TitleBarSeparator" />
```

Where `TitleBarSeparator` is:

```
<style name="TitleBarSeparator">
    <item name="android:layout_width">1px</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/title_separator</item>
</style>
```

I've tried:

```
new ImageView(getContext(), null, R.style.TitleBarSeparator);
```

but it doesn't work.
I guess the error comes from passing null as `AttributeSet` but I am not completely sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to fix it.

```
View v = new ImageView(getContext());
v.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(1, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
v.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.title_separator));
```

Still, I would like to have a way to set the style.