# Adding ImageView to TableRow doesn't show

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablayout

**EDIT:** it seems like the problem is that creating a new ImageView programatically and providing the style in the constructor just doesn't really work, much like what is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191631/creating-an-imageview-with-a-certain-style-programatically). Adding all the individual attributes of the style programatically solves the problem, but if someone does find a cleaner solution it would still be much appreciated.

**Original Question**

Like many other questions on this site, I am trying to add images to a TableLayout programatically. The first picture in the table is already included in the activity's xml and is displayed well. I want all new images to have the same style, but when I try to add them through the code they simply doesn't show. I tried several variations of the code but none of them seem to work. This is the relevant part of the current version:

```
    TableLayout picturesTable = findViewById(R.id.pictures_table);
    currentPicture.setImageURI(uri);
    TableRow lastRow = (TableRow) picturesTable.
            getChildAt(picturesTable.getChildCount() - 1);
    ImageView newPic = new ImageView(this, null, R.style.UploadPicture);
    lastRow.addView(newPic);
```

The relevant style:

```
<style name="UploadPicture">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:contentDescription">@string/empty_post_pic_description</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:onClick">open_file_search</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="srcCompat">@drawable/pic_upload_plus</item>
</style>
```

The TableLayout:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/pictures_table"
    android:layout_width="330dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.51"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pic_1"
            style="@style/UploadPicture" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Since my style contains a values for layout_width, layout_height and layout_weight, I really am not sure why the first picture is displayed well but the pictures added through code aren't.

@drawable/pic_upload_plus is a valid png that is displayed well for the first picture.

Comment: row add into table and table add into view at the end

Comment: you need to set layout params to image added dynamically.

Comment: @AndroidTeam the row is already a child of the table, why do I need to add it again?

Comment: @KaranMer The layout parameters are already a part of the style. And in addition, even if I change the addView invocation to:
lastRow.addView(newPic, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1));

it doesn't work

Comment: @DeanGurvitz you are using wrong layout params, Try with `new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);`

Comment: @KaranMer that doesn't work either. It seems like the style just doesn't register for the uploaded image, similar to the problem experienced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191631/creating-an-imageview-with-a-certain-style-programatically)